# C# byte find string representation of all bits set/not set

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation, custom-attributes

Sorry if this is a repeat question, I tried searching but I couldn't find anything that relates to my problem.

I have a byte value in which each bit (or group of bits) means something. I have an enum with a custom attribute to define those bits, as so:

```
[Flags]
public enum Config4
{
    [StringValue("Enable good-read beep")]
    GoodReadBeep = 1 << 0,
    [StringValue("Low beeper volume")]
    LowBeep = 1 << 1,
    [StringValue("Medium beeper volume")]
    MediumBeep = 1 << 2,
    [StringValue("Low beeper frequency")]
    LowFrequency = 1 << 3,
    [StringValue("Medium beeper frequency")]
    MediumFrequency = 1 << 4,
    [StringValue("Medium beeper duration")]
    MediumDuration = 1 << 5,
    [StringValue("Long beeper duration")]
    LongDuration = 1 << 6,
    [StringValue("Reserved")]
    Reserved = 1 << 7
}
```

The catch is that apart from these individual definitions, pairs (or even groups) of bits are defined something else. For example, `(LowBeep | MediumBeep) = HighBeep`.

Lets say I have a byte value 47 that I want to find the string representation to. The method i have implemented currently involves finding the number of bits set in the byte, then iterating through those bits and appending the string value from the enum. Something like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bitsSet.Count; i++)
{
    answer += ((ConfigDataHolder.Config4)bitsSet[i]).GetStringValue() + ", ";
}
```

This poses a problem when groups of bits are defined. In the case mentioned above, 47 would contain both `MediumBeep` and `LowBeep` and thus the string representation shoud be `HighBeep` instead of `MediumBeep` and `LowBeep` individually.

Is there a more effecient way to fetch the string representation of each bit set in the byte considering there could be groups of bits that mean something completely different than if the individual bits were set?

Thanks
Rishi

Comment: Surely it's `(LowBeep | MediumBeep) = HighBeep` ? Otherwise `HighBeep` would be zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitmasks. Take a look at the small example here :

```
[Flags]
public enum MySettings
{
    SettingA=1,
    SettingB=2,
    SettingC=4,
    SettingD=8
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte mySettings1 = 7;
        byte mySettings2 = 2;

        Console.WriteLine("Analyse mySetting1");
        AnalyseSettings(mySettings1);
        Console.WriteLine("Analyse mySetting2");
        AnalyseSettings(mySettings2);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void AnalyseSettings(byte mySettings)
    {
        byte maskA = 1;
        byte maskB = 2;
        byte maskC = 4;
        byte maskD = 8;

        // Compare with bitwise and 

        if ((mySettings & maskA) == maskA)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A Selected");
        }

        if ((mySettings & maskB) == maskB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B Selected");
        }
        if ((mySettings & maskC) == maskC)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C Selected");
        }
        if ((mySettings & maskD) == maskD)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("D Selected");
        }
    }
}
```

It's pretty fast to compare bitwise and you can add the result to a string builder.
I don't use the shift operator in my enum declaration, but it's the same.

Comment: I thought of doing that, but this what would the mask be if there were multiple bits making up a setting? In my example, what would the byte mask be for the 'HighBeep'?

Comment: Also, in this code snippet I can't seem to figure out where you're using the enum. Its essentially sending a byte and comparing it with the local mask variable, correct? If I try to execute the "if" statement with the enum value, I get a compiler error basically telling me I can't AND a byte and an enum value.

Comment: Sorry for delay. You can convert you bitflag enum to an int. See the updated source below.

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine them. See here :

```
        byte maskAndB = 3;
        if ((mySettings & maskAndB) == maskAndB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" A and B selected");
        }
```

It's like the binary representation of the numbers. 11 = 3 and 101 = 5.

I wonder why you want to use the shift operator? You're also using a left shift and start at the highest bit of your data type.

You can also convert your enum to an int and do the check again:

```
[Flags]
public enum MySettings
{
    SettingA=1,
    SettingB=2,
    SettingC=4,
    SettingD=8
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var settingsFlags1 = MySettings.SettingA | MySettings.SettingB;
        var settingsFlags2 = MySettings.SettingB | MySettings.SettingC | MySettings.SettingD;


        int mySettings1 = (int)settingsFlags1;
        int mySettings2 = (int)settingsFlags2;

        Console.WriteLine("Analyse mySetting1");
        AnalyseSettings(mySettings1);
        Console.WriteLine("Analyse mySetting2");
        AnalyseSettings(mySettings2);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void AnalyseSettings(int mySettings)
    {
// ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure. This would mean though that I will have to have a mask for each possible combination, correct? 

And no particular reason to use the shift operator. It makes it easier for me to read, you look at how much the shift is by and you know which bit is being mapped to that enum value. No need to figure out if its the 7th of the 8th bit.

Comment: If it works for you you could start with the lowest bit. What kind of masks you need depends on your concrete situation.  If this is a common scenario, why not?  In my old job I need a mask for each bit to figure out the the state of our hardware device (card found, power on, etc.) and that worked fine